# bootstrap 3 responsive mega menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have tried a lot, but i can't solve this problem,

problem as menu is can't show responsive.

i try responsive menu like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LAwjG/)**

And Want Like this [image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown pink"> <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Services </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown rama"> <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Products </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="left:-250px !important; width:800px; " role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
              <div class="nav-product"  role="main">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="pink">Labour Manage. System</h4>
                      <p>There Managing Contractor's Labours / Workers at the entry points with rich GUI... <a href="#">Read More</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/crm-nav-icon.png" alt="eXiger CRM System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="rama" >eXiger CRM System</h4>
                      <p>awidely implemented strategy for managing a company's interactions with customers....<a href="#">Read More</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/payroll-nav-icon.png" alt="Payroll Management" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="blue">Payroll Management</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media"> <img src="img/lms-nav-icon.png" alt="Labour Management System" class="pull-left"/>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4>Subheading</h4>
                      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown green"> <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Technology </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown purple"> <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Marketing </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown orange"> <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">About Us </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="pinkdark"><a href="#" >Request a Quote</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliexalter/DAmEv/) I used `col-md-4` and img class `img-circle`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If not late, I've made this megamenu for bootstrap 3 http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/, perhaps it could help you to get the idea.

Comment: Hey @geedmo i just stumbled upon your mega menu first off great work on this! It will work great for me so i appreciate that!But i was wondering how you can change it from click to hover? Is that possible with the way that you have it coded?

Cheers!

Comment: In the same way the ".dropdown.open" works, this rule opens the menu on hover .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu { display: block; }

Comment: @geedmo... great work on the yamm. I'm just curious, when you narrow down the browser, to somewhere around 300px or so, I noticed the sandwich icon goes outside of its container. there is also a limit as to how narrow you can make the browser window. After a certain width, it becomes solid. Where do you set those vals? Or how do you make sure that sandwich stays in the expected boundary?